# plot 3d numpy array as a 3d image using matplotlib or PIL

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, python-imaging-library

After looking at various related answers, I could not figure out a straight way.

I have a 3-d numpy array of shape `(390, 280, 160)`. I want to visualize this as an image. What could be the simplest way to do it?

Comment: Images represent 2D data.  How do you expect a visualization of 3D data to appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a minimal example of volumetric plot using mayavi.
You can find more examples of 3d data visualization [here](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html#visualizing-volumetric-scalar-data)

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np

s = np.random.rand(20, 20, 20)
volume = mlab.pipeline.volume(mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(s), vmin=0, vmax=0.8)

mlab.draw()
mlab.savefig('output.png')
```

[image]

From mayavi docs

> For such a visualization, tweaking the opacity transfer function is
>   critical to achieve a good effect. Typically, it can be useful to
>   limit the lower and upper values to the 20 and 80 percentiles of the
>   data, in order to have a reasonable fraction of the volume
>   transparent.

Comment: I tried with mayavi on jupyter notebook but it seems to be not working. Is it possible to do it in an alternative way?

Comment: @user10050371, apparently neither matplotlib not PIL is not intended for 3d visualization. Did you follow [this](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/tips.html#using-mayavi-in-jupyter-notebooks) guide for mayavi with jupyter?

Comment: I tried it by saving the figure, using  mlab.savefig('a.png'). It saves an image but the image is homogeneous and has full green color whereas random generator would not have this structure.

Comment: @user10050371, Try adding `mlab.draw()` before `mlab.save()`. I think I've had the same issue as well.

Comment: @user10050371, I updated my answer with the output image.

Comment: So, what kind of the output do you expect? Why didn't you include the desired output in your question, so I no one has to guess?

Comment: Thanks! The output has to correspond to the pixel values, I don't think the random values you generated will have homogeneous or near to green color as shown in the image. There is some problem with your output, I am not sure!!

Comment: @user10050371, it is simply an artifact of the semi-transparent color map and the use of random data. I have changed an example a bit to get rid of the uniformity.